# Loop through a subset then the main set C#, Razor, linq, Umbraco

Tags: c#, .net, linq, razor, umbraco

I am trying to add a featured items feature to my page in umbraco where people can add the pages they want to highlight and then compare those IDs with the search results and output the featured items first then iterate through the rest of the results.

So I have

```
@foreach (var property in Model.SearchResults.Properties)
{}
```

and I know I can use Linq to do a where for the ID array but how would I then iterate through the rest of the items? Would I need two loops? One with the IDs included and one with them excluded?

e.g.

```
var allPropeties = Model.SearchResults.Properties();
var featuredIDs= new [1,22,55,84,1234];
var featuredItems= allProperties.Where(x => featuredIDs.Contains(x.Id)).ToArray();
```

I'm new to C# and Linq so I'm not sure of the flexibility yet. apologies if this is a duplicate of another question but I couldn't find it anywhere!

Umbraco consumes our property management software, each property has a unique ID as well as property data such as addresses, images etc... the API dumps that info,1 page per property on Umbraco. The code to consume that info and output in the search is there.

We currently output the property search/listing page using the simple foreach at the top of the question.

What I'm trying to work out is if I can force this to output the featured properties first or if I have to separate the logic and loop through featured if they exist then output the rest excluding the featured list.

```
var allPropeties = Model.SearchResults.Properties();
if(Model.Content.FeaturedProps){
var featuredIDs= Model.Content.FeaturedProps;
var featuredItems= allProperties.Where(x => featuredIDs.Contains(x.Id));
}
```

The goal is to add 5 - 10 featured properties per listing page as seen on our [website](https://www.galbraithgroup.com/sales-and-lettings/search/?sq.BuyOrLet=true)

Comment: Can you explain with data example what you want to achieve with this query?

Comment: I've updated the question with more info, examples will be added as soon as I have more time to do it!

Comment: The thing is that I would be glad to help you, but I'm not sure what do you want to loop besides the loop that you already have. I am not asking for the actual data, dummy data that you made up would be great.

Comment: For example, if you implement the code with the two loops that you do not want, that would probably give me the insight I need to address your problem.

Comment: My lack of terminology is impacting this I think! I've updated and also added a link to the website I'm currently attempting to expand upon.

Comment: Do you intend to load all properties but have the featured items at the start of the result?

Comment: @LajosArpad yes that's what I'd like to do ideally

Answer (score 0):

Since you want all records in the results and you want to order them descendingly by their id being contained by the set. So, **instead** of the `Where`, we will need `OrderByDescending`:

```
.OrderByDescending(x => featureIDs.Contains(x.Id))
```

You were using the right condition in the wrong clause.

Comment: Thanks I'll give it a shot and see what I get!

Comment: @Squidgybuffalo happy to help. Let me know the result.

Comment: @Squidgybuffalo I had some mistyping in the answer. Edited it.

Comment: Sorry work's been crazy so I've not be able to try this out yet, will let you know once I get the time :D

Comment: @Squidgybuffalo no worries, no hurries on my end.